# Joomla custom types / custom fields without plugin?

Tags: php, joomla, migration, joomla-extensions, joomla-k2

I am currently tasked with maintaining two Joomla websites built with Yoo theme, which uses Zoo for custom content types and custom fields. I have heard that in recent versions of Joomla there is native support for such things, rendering extensions like Zoo or K2 redundant, allowing us to take a more native Joomla approach.

[This company](https://www.cms2cms.com/) seems to offer an option to migrate "Joomla Zoo" to "Joomla!", seeming to imply that this is possible, but it is difficult to tell for sure based on reading their site.

Is this true? I have been unable to turn up much information through the usual scouring of Google. If so then we would like to explore the possibility of removing Zoo from the project as it is a real pain to use.

Comment: I would write a plugin of your own to add these fields to your content: https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin Probibly even incorporate it into your template if you are using a template solely for this company, that way it is a complete package and more easily migrateable.

Comment: Your thought that Joomla! core would be "rendering extensions like Zoo or K2 redundant" is not so accurate. It may be your personal preference, but there will always be additional features inside those extensions that add benefit to a Joomla! site far beyond custom fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's planned for future versions of Joomla! a native custom fields feature, at this time you can  do this in this possible ways without an extension:

- **Creating a custom form field type**
  https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type
- **Adding custom fields to core components using a plugin**
  https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin
- **Standard form field types**
  https://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types

---

*Find more info here:*
*https://joomla.digital-peak.com/blog/198-custom-fields-in-joomla-3-6
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDh1IPuZAVA*